Is the word "done" needed?
I found this line from Killers Of The Flower Moon (2023):

Ramsey: Whoo-hoo. Partner. Look what I done found in the possum hole.

Is the word "done" needed?

That construction with "done" is non-standard southern Anerican English regional dialect. Poor, uneducated characters in a William Faulkner novel often use it, for example.

@FumbleFingers  this might help https://scrapsfromtheloft.com/movies/killers-of-the-flower-moon-2023-transcript/

@Mari-LouA Thank you.

@Mari-LouA: Over the last 24 hours I've actually downloaded 3 different subtitle files for the movie, and have rarely found any of the OP's cited text. But I finally just retrieved my own backup copy of the movie with subtitle, and everything seems to be there. I have no idea why so many of the subtitles seem to be different - perhaps it's because it's an inordinately long movie, at 3:38

@FumbleFingers all the quotes in Rush D's questions are in the script. If you've just  found your backup everything is well. I'll leave the link for other users to use. The OP could also edit their posts and include this link in all their questions related to the movie.

@FumbleFingers -  been there, done that, got the T-shirt! Often films came out in different versions: cineman Blu-Ray, DVD, cinema etc. Different lengths, scenes cut out for some markets, added for others

@MichaelHarvey: Also some subtitle files are produced by non-native Anglophones transcribing "pre-release" copies of major new movies, before the final version appears (often, only in cinemas initially, followed by bluray and/or streaming). It's a veritable minefield!

@FumbleFingers - I mainly use English subtitles for foreign language films. Apart from already mentioned problems I could include machine (Babelfish type) translations. Amateur translations can vary in quality wildly. The best are the official ones.

@MichaelHarvey: I got into the habit of collecting subtitles with movies for my father, but now my daughter's going deaf, so she appreciates them! The "official" subtitles may be better on average, but I've noticed that they sometimes have what was in the script, where a hand-transcribed version reflects what the actor actually said. But in my experience, if I can't catch the exact words in a Youtube video, the chances of Youtube's auto-generated subtitles giving me any help are about zero!

@FumbleFingers - other annoyances include titles for European films where 'euros' is translated to 'dollars', and, very annoying, this, names of government organisations changed to the nearest dumbed-down US equivalent (e.g. la Gendarmerie becomes 'the FBI' and le procureur de la ville becomes 'the DA'.

I notice many mistakes in subtitles when added by an independent titler. It's as though they write what they thought they heard without reference to the script or fully understanding the flow. Obviously I'm not watching with the script beside me, but frequently think "that's nonsense". And paraphrasing is quite usual.

@WeatherVane - translation is a considerable art; even in a novel, where the reader has all the time in the world, it takes a very particular talent to do justice to the original in terms of subtlety, especially if there is a culture gap between source and target cultures (there always is!). I notice this between French and English. It is a lot more tricky subtitling a film when you have to condense what someone says into a readable form that can be digested before the next thing comes along, and even the best can be more or less crude summarisations.

To answer your question, no, the word done is not necessary. In this example, however, it means just:
Look what I just found in the possum hole.
How done is used is an example of the way an uneducated white person in the South might speak. You shouldn't try to imitate this.

The sentence without done would be "Look what I found...", which is standard English.

I assume the unwanted done in such contexts is intended to unambiguously convey past tense (as in "He done upset me"). But found is obviously past tense anyway.

done is often analyzed as a perfective marker: https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/perfective-done

@TimR: In my simplistic view of things, "perfective" in such contexts implies completed. But the very first example that came to mind for me when I saw this question was the extremely common line "You done kilt (killed) me!" in westerns, where the "gut-shot" victim knows he's definitely not gonna survive, but he ain't dead yet. Odd, that.

@FumbleFingers  Not an issue if "kilt me" is understood to mean "dealt me a fatal wound".

There is also "I've done looking for it" which means you have stopped the activity.
